# UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate willPresent doesn't work with OneSignal

Tags: swift, apple-push-notifications, ios10, onesignal

I'm using OneSignal to send Push Notification, I ran into the problem that on iOS 10 the method func `userNotificationCenter (_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void)` does not work, and `UIAlertController` appears, Instead of the standard Banner. What do I need to do to make this method work on iOS 10 and to display the standard banner?

Alert looks like this now
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was prompted to solve this issue [here](https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-iOS-SDK/issues/214#issuecomment-288950063). It works.

```
  OneSignal.initWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions, appId: appID, handleNotificationAction: { (notificationResult) in

        }, settings: [kOSSettingsKeyInFocusDisplayOption : OSNotificationDisplayType.notification.rawValue])
```

Comment: Incase someone runs into the same issue as me, this setting is saved in storage so if the above code seems to not work just uninstall and reinstall the application.